# Data not refreshing in netTier DAL- possibly caching issue?

Tags: entity-framework, caching, data-access-layer, codesmith, .nettiers

We're having a strange issue with one entity/data-source seemingly caching data in Data Access layer.

Basically the tables are a standard SQL Server table (SQL server 2008 R2). The code is generated the same way using the same template(NetTier 2.3.1) and Code-smith generator 6.5, there's nothing unusual about this procedure of creating DAL files.

BUT... when the tables are updated through custome procedures or outside of DAL , our web app doesn't display the latest data - sometimes it does, but sometimes it takes a few minutes for the latest data to come through. I can query the SQL database directly and see the updated data immediately, so it's not a database/lag issue.

Just to verify - I added a custom stored proc and tried getting the data that way, rather than accessing the table directly through the repository - this doesn't work either, it being an issue with the entity itself.

Any ideas? I wondered about entity caching, not sure how I can see the settings for that. Please note that we are using following tools:

Code-smith generator 6.5
NetTier 2.3.1
SQL Server 2008 R2
Project is hosted on IIS 7with .net Framework 2.0

This is an strange issue and we are facing lot of issues with caching of data. Please do reply if you have any idea ...

thanks,
Shankar..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have entity tracking turned on (http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16/p/9639/35883.aspx)? What are your .netTiers config settings?

Comment: Thanks for reply.

See I am using Codesmith Generator 6.5 and nettier 2.3.1 for generating DAL files. It doesn't show me option entity tracking in config file.

may I need to upgrade these tools ? Is this bug for this versions?

kindly reply, we are getting this issues frequently. Let me know If you want to see config file.